# Crash at default destructor of UNused class

Tags: c++, multithreading, crash, cmake

I have a cmake-based package. It has several target-executable. One of the targets crashes from time to time. The back trace looks like:

```
...
#19 XXX::~XXX (this=0x69a120, 
    __in_chrg=<value optimized out>)
at /package_path/XXX.h:44
...
```

But I don't create any instance of XXX object for this target at all. Even more - I do not include "XXX.h" file (checked with grep).

How is this possible?

---

P.S. More info:

The package has two target executable files, one is parallel version, second is - one-core version.
One-core version never crashes.

Comment: Its really hard to tell with the info provided. Try putting some traces in the constructor of the unused class.

Comment: You don't include XXX.h but can you be sure that none of the headers you included didn't do that?

Comment: @Tomek, Yes. XXX is my class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My mistake.
The XXX file was used in different directory of the project, which I didn't check by mistake.